# Mutate array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to check my todo list and change the status but I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Here is my code:

```js
handleChange = (id) => {
    let data = [...this.state.data];
    let indexOfTodo = data.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);
    data[indexOfTodo].checked = !data[indexOfTodo].checked;
    console.log(data[indexOfTodo]);
    console.log(data)
}
```

I hit the button twice and here is the `console.log`

[image]

Sorry for dummy question. I am new in react

Comment: Were are you telling React to update?, normally this is with setState.

Comment: I know but before setState I want to check the data is updated correctly

Comment: I'd recommend to read https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to mutate the `data[indexOfTodo]` object, but instead create a copy of it with the `checked` property changed.

You must also put the updated array in state with `setState` for your component to re-render. You can use the function version of `setState` since your update is derived from data that is in your state.

```
handleChange = id => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    let data = [...previousState.data];
    let indexOfTodo = data.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);

    data[indexOfTodo] = {
      ...data[indexOfTodo],
      checked: !data[indexOfTodo].checked
    };

    return { data };
  });
};
```

Comment: previousState is the best practice when calling setState?

Comment: If your state update is derived from data that is already in your state (like your example), it is best to give a function to `setState` that uses the previous state and returns the state update, yes. If it is not derived from data already in the state you can use an object, like e.g. `onChange = (event) => { this.setState({ value: event.target.value }); }`.

Comment: Thanks alot Tholle

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code but to reflect the value in the state you need to call setState method.

You can use the below code:

```
handleChange= (id) => {
    let a = this.state.data[id].checked;
    let todo = update(this.state.data, { [id]: { checked: { $set: !a } } })
    this.setState({ data: todo });
};
```

To use `update` function. Need to import immutable helper:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
```